Magento admin redirecting to 404 not found , showing media/admin URL
There is an  issue arising with a app admin page is redirecting to media/admin and showing 404. Tried clearing cache as well as tried redeploying static content but the issue persists. Checked for the htaccesss  and it seems fine as well.
https://avenueretail.co.uk/admin
getting redirected to
https://avenueretail.co.uk/media/admin/admin/index/index/key/ae6fc3c55da773416b13f37c4c1b9c14f6143d2e456859eac5f59b733ce4c3af/
Apologize cannot share server or any other details
Tried clearing redis  cache as well, used setup:Store commands as  well


I still access the site's admin login page normally, is there an error after logging in as admin?

no error just a 404 checked every log but no fruitful result

Working now, seems its fixed somehow
